# Append string to file names with bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a folder containing some HTML files and I want to obtain some URLs based on the file names. So, or example, I have these files:

- hello.html
- goodby.html
- iloveyou.html

And I want to get:

- http://google.com/hello.html
- http://google.com/goodby.html
- http://google.com/iloveyou.html

How do I do that with bash?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
for FILE in folder/*.html
do
  do_something_with "http://google.com/${FILE}"
done
```

Comment: Generally a good answer -- only note here is that the use of an all-caps variable name is contrary to convention. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or POSIX-specified utilities, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict with the behavior of a compliant (read: non-zsh) shell. (Otherwise, people can all too easily run `for PATH in ...`, and then wonder why they can no longer run external commands).

Comment: Ha! Good point. I learned something, thanks.